# DataFactory - missing table in dataset

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure DataFactory.
I'm creating a pipeline and wish to connect to table via linked service.
I've created a linked service to the DB -  the connection is successful.
When i try to create a Dataset with the linked service to the db,
and try to choose the table for the dataset (AZURE SQL),
there are no tables to choose from (Example in picture)

I need to choose a table for the dataset,
What am i doing wrong?

[image: Add table Name]

Answer (score 0):

if you managed to do a connection with the DB then your credentials are correct

try this approach:

create a pipeline in ADF, drag an activity , lets suppose its a lookUp activity .
Drag this activity to the board/Canvas .
click on the lookup activity -> settings tab

**in settings tab**: source dataset -> your dataset
on the same tab : you will see table drop down list, if your connection is correct , you need to specify which table you want to connect , after you finish,click on OK. this should work.
if you dont see your dataset in the drop down list, try creating it again :

under settings in lookup activity :

source dataset -> new -> azure sql database -> click on continue
enter a name to the dataset , after that under the linked service tab :
click on new ,enter server name + credentials , test your connection and click on create

Can you please explain how did you create the dataset ? maybe something is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you have selected the correct database in the linked service and the tables are available in the database, the tables list should be available in the drop-down.

[image]

1. Make sure you have selected the correct database in your linked service.
2. Make sure the tables are available in the selected database. If tables were not created in the database, then the drop-down list of tables to choose in the Table name will not show anything (none).
3. Sometimes, refreshing the table name gives the list if the tables are available in the database.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I needed to refresh the list, as i edited the linked service before. Sorry, seems silly now that i think of it.